# Google App Engine service (module) not starting, and flooding 404's to /_ah/start

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm refactoring an existing codebase. I switched from using the appcfg.py to using the gcloud command, which seemed to go fine. Our entire codebase was running on one default frontend instance, which I'm now trying to break into services. To start, I created one "worker" backend service, and I'm using a cron job to test.

I can see the worker in the console, but no instance is started. The logs for that service are rapidly flooded with 404's to /_ah/start. I've tried manual and basic scaling. The documentation states that it's okay not to have a startup script, and that a 404 at that endpoint is considered success. However, the instance is not starting.

**Logs**
[image: logs rapidly filling with 404's]

**worker.yaml**

```
service: worker
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: B2
manual_scaling:
        instances: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /work/.*
  script: worker.app
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

**worker.py**

```
import webapp2
import handlers

config = {
    #...
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(
        '/work/test<:/?>',
        handlers.Test,
        methods=['GET'],
    ),
], debug=True, config=config)
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:

    - url: "*/work/*"
    module: worker
```

Comment: for your `script: worker_test. app`  line in your `worker. yaml` you need a worker_test. py file (not worker. py)...

Comment: That was a mistake in my question, in the actual files it was correctly `script: worker.app`. Updated post.

Comment: personally I also prefer to specify the app in the `. yaml ` file, to leave no room for human error during deployment. Maybe leave the default scaling for now, until you get things going - then you can check if the service is deployed and the instance starts